# What would cause Memcached to Hang for 2+ seconds?

Tags: networking, php, solaris, memcached, scalability

I'm going nuts trying to scale memcached. From their site:

> Memcached operations are almost all O(1). Connecting to it and issuing a get or stat command should never lag. If connecting lags, you may be hitting the max connections limit. See ServerMaint for details on stats to monitor.
>
> If issuing commands lags, you can have a number of tuning problems. Most common are hardware problems, not enough RAM (swapping), network problems (bandwidth, dropped packets, half-duplex connections). On rare occasion OS bugs or memcached bugs can contribute.

Well.. it is most certainly not performing like an O(1) operation for me. Under low to normal load on our site memcached response times for get and set ops are about 0.001 seconds. Not bad. But if we triple the load we get outliers that take 100x (or in rare cases 1000x!) that long. I even had one instance where it took 2.2442 seconds for memcached to store a value.

Obviously this is killing our site.

Here's the output of Memcached->getStats during one of the slow periods:

```
        [pid] => 18079
        [uptime] => 8903
        [threads] => 4
        [time] => 1332795759
        [pointer_size] => 32
        [rusage_user_seconds] => 26
        [rusage_user_microseconds] => 503872
        [rusage_system_seconds] => 125
        [rusage_system_microseconds] => 477008
        [curr_items] => 42099
        [total_items] => 422500
        [limit_maxbytes] => 943718400
        [curr_connections] => 84
        [total_connections] => 4946
        [connection_structures] => 178
        [bytes] => 7259957
        [cmd_get] => 1679091
        [cmd_set] => 351809
        [get_hits] => 1662048
        [get_misses] => 17043
        [evictions] => 0
        [bytes_read] => 109388476
        [bytes_written] => 3187646458
        [version] => 1.4.13
```

So things that I have ruled out so far are:

- Hitting the max connections limit (`curr_connections` of 84 is well below the default of max of 1024)
- Swapping - the machine has 900M out of 1024M of memory dedicated to memcached on a dedicated machine. It only appears to be using about 7MB of data as per the `bytes` stat.

How would I diagnose the other hardware problems? prstat doesn't really show a whole lot going on in terms of CPU or memory usage. Not sure how to figure out the network problems but as this is a dedicated server on the same private network as the web box I don't think it's a connectivity issue (`ping` is less than a millisecond between the boxes).

Is there something else I'm missing here? It's driving me nuts.

Edit: Also forgot to mention that I've tried both persistent and non-persistent connections with minimal-to-no impact.

Comment: " I even had one instance where it took 2.2442 seconds for memcached to store a value." How big is the payload you are storing?

Comment: Mike - It was all small test values: `$to_store = json_encode(array('dummy'=>'some data','hey'=>1,'this'=>'is just fake data i am putting in to test with...'));`

Comment: How many servers in the pool, just the one?

Comment: Yes, just one for now.

Comment: Have you tried `lsof` (list of open files) on the memcached pid? When I end up with "lag" issues I run this command to see what exactly is going on with the process.

Comment: I don't have `lsof` available but I do have `pfiles` which appears to be similar. Not really sure how to read the output though: http://pastebin.com/hZYWdPPy

Comment: Hmmm not sure on that output. Which distro you running? Do you notice the lag if you were to restart the daemon? Or does it seem to build up as contents gets added?

Comment: It's Joyent SmartOS (Solaris derivative). It doesnt seem to be correlated with server uptime just with traffic spikes.

Comment: Which php extension are you using? memcached or memcache? and versions? And what do you get when you run `pargs` on the memcached pid?

Comment: It's the `Memcached` extension 2.0.0b2 with `libmemcached` 0.43 (working on getting those updated to the most recent versions this week). `pargs` is: `18079:  /opt/local/bin/memcached -d -u memcached -l 10.12.25.172 -m 900`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the calling machine was using up all its CPU which was causing its TCP connections to lag heavily. Scaling the web tier horizontally fixed the problem. This turned out not to be a memcached issue at all -- that's just where the symptoms of this other problem were cropping up.

Answer (score 2):

Memcached performance can degrade significantly if it uses swap memory. If you notice that swap memory is being used on your server, you can try starting memcached with the `-k` option.

From: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewHardware#Avoid_Swapping

> Avoid Swapping
>
> Assign physical memory, with a few percent extra, to a memcached server. Do not over-allocate memory and expect swap to save you. Performance will be very, very poor. Take extra care to monitor if your server is using swap, and tune if necessary.

Comment: As noted in the original post swap is not being used. There is only 7mb of data in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

I changed operating systems from SmartOS to Ubuntu and the problem seems to be resolved. Not sure why but it appears to have been an issue between memcached and the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you actually have persistent connections working like you think you do. (Hi original question of mine from 6 years ago... still ❤️ you...)